# javax.validation.ConstraintViolation not found when updating to seam 2.3.0.Final

Tags: java, seam2

I'm trying to upgrade my project from Seam 2.2.1.CR2 to 2.3.0.Final but when doing so
I'm getting a:

```
cannot access javax.validation.ConstraintViolation
class file for javax.validation.ConstraintViolation not found
```

I have traced the error down to StatusMessages.java. In that class
it can't find the ConstraintViolation class when doing import javax.validation.ConstraintViolation;

Since StatusMessages.java is a class found package org.jboss.seam.international; I can't make
any changes to it.

What is missing?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have the validation-api.jar referenced in your project.